# Getting 'std::bad_alloc' when launching a compiled third-party program due to compilation?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I am trying to run a program (MergeMap, http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~yonghui/mgmap.html) that I compiled on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 13.04 x86-64) but, from the first step, it throws this error:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc
    Abortado (`core' generado)
```

Note: just to make it clear, the problem doesn't arise when compiling (here, everything seems ok), but when launching it.

In any case, it seems to be a problem allocating memory but it is not: I already compiled the same program in the same personal computer few weeks ago (yes, I am so stupid to erase it) and it was working (with the same data) really well. Then, I'm launching it in a big server (my PC will never have same possibilities to allocate memory than this server) and I'm getting the same problem. When I launch it with the sample input data proposed in its website, that it is even smaller than my data working few weeks ago, it also crash. I'm getting crazy. :-o

So, could it be that I'm now compiling the same program with different options (in relation to the compilation of few weeks ago) and these options make the launching of the program collapse??? If possible, how could I solve it when compiling??

Thanks.

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is a C++ construction so why oh why the tag `C`?

Comment: Compile your program and the external library with `g++ -Wall -g`. Improve the code till you got no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb` and also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/); perhaps ask the author of the library....

Comment: @Jongware ... because of my ignorance (Perl programmer). Thanks.

Comment: How are you compiling now? Did you compile on the server or on your personal computer?

Comment: @Michael On both (with same result when executing). And how I'm compiling? For example, with g++ -fno-stack-protector -o main.o -c -g main.cpp -I/usr/include/boost (I also tried -same result too- without the '-fno-stack-protector' because I was not sure if last time -when worked- I used it)

Comment: Have you copied the executable from your machine to the big server? Do your machine and the big server have the same version of gcc installed?

Comment: Load in gdb, place a breakpoint on __cxa_throw and run. You should stop on the offending allocation. Walk up the stack and examine the variables. You are probably passing too large (or negative) size to the `new` operator.

Comment: @n.m. They have different version of gcc (SERVER: gcc versión 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) // MY PC: gcc versión 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)), but I'm compiling each time on the different place (not copying the executable). For the second comment, I will try to get deeper on gdb use; nevertheless, I can assume the problem allocating memory when executing could be due to the compiling process, isn't it?

Comment: @Jose: no, memory allocation problems are not because of issues when compiling, but because of bugs in the C++ source code. Changing the compiler should not fix memory bugs; but upgrading the compiler could help to find some of them (because new compilers give better warnings), but you'll have to work. Current version of GCC is 4.8.2 (so 4.4.6 is an ancient version)

Comment: It theoretically could be a problem in compilation process, if you mix and match objects compiled with different versions of the compiler. But as you say it's not the case. It could also be a compiler or library bug. You can try to use a newer gcc and boost versions on your server (the easiest way is to compile them from source and install under your $HOME, no root needed; you will have to compile/run your program in such a way that it can find the shared libraries it was linked against; setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is probably the easiest way).

Comment: did you copy the source code to the server, or did you download it there separately? If it has a makefile try make clean. if not, try removing all the *.o file from that directory. Also, the problem may arise from different library versions that are used by the program. Anyway... you need to debug it, or better yet ask the help from the author.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you (Michael, n.m. and Basile)! It will be not easy but I will try to go deeper debugging it. Thanks!